# How can/does one dynamically adjust line width using Excel?

Tags: microsoft-excel, microsoft-excel-2007

I have a series of figures that look like the "Basic Radial" SmartArt Graphic in Excel.

My goal would be to be able to change the width of each line using values in values found in my worksheet, thus in a dynamic fashion, so that I don't have to go and do this line by line. I've been going through other posts describing how to do this for column widths, but these workarounds don't seem to correlate with what I"m trying to do. Any and all help that woud save me hours from doing this would be much appreciated.

Comment: Figures? Like, charts? You could write a macro in VBa to update them.

Answer (score 3):

As suggested, you need a vba macro. The easieast way is recording a macro and then manual change the width. After this study the recorded macro and try to optimize it.